# What should be an ideal Jmeter Testing Enviornment with an application hosted on a server?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, client-side, jmeter-5.0

1.We have an Open Finn Application hosted on a US server.
2.We are using Jmeter to get the performance of different modules like login logout time.
3.While recording and running the jmter test plan with all embedded elements we are getting time similiar to Manual performance results.
4.But when we ruin the same test plan on the server where the application is hosted the results are way too fast and different from manual performance data we got on server.

Now it is difficult to judge which data is correct and which is not.
-Is The approach mentioned above correct and how to get the results ins sync with manual performance on server and local machine.

[Local Machine Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBfja.png)
[Server Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJyA.png)

While we are running the application manually and noting the timings on local machine and server they are almost similar.

But while running the JMeter the results vary with a large degree.

The expectation is to get the manual and JMeter data at par on local machine and on Server.

i have applied all header managers cache managers and dynamic regular expressions to makee it closer to real client side simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a scenario where you're in the process of loading data from your local machine. In this situation, you're essentially dispatching a request over the vast expanse of the internet, traversing through the intricate web of your office or home network. This journey involves numerous 'hops', or intermediary points, before it finally arrives at its intended destination – the server.

Now, consider an alternative scenario where you're sending a request from within the very environment where the application resides. This approach brings you much closer to the server, significantly minimizing the distance your request needs to cover. Of course, the proximity ultimately depends on the nature of the endpoint – whether it's an internal or external node in the network topology. This distinction is crucial, as it dictates the efficiency and speed with which your request is processed.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Yugal, But where should the test plan executed on server or local machine as client may not be using the same server where the application is hosted also manual performance do not have much difference on time on server and on local machine but jmeter differs with a large degree.

Comment: For an effective load test, it is imperative that you execute it within the environment where the server is hosted. The primary objective of load testing is to assess the server's ability to handle increased load and traffic. In this context, the client-side metrics become secondary and are not the focus of the evaluation. The core goal is to determine whether your server can effectively scale and respond to varying levels of load, ensuring its reliability and performance under demanding conditions.

Comment: Hey Yug from load testing perspective you are right but i also want to get performance of each http request and get the elapsed time of each module to get to know how much time my each module is taking and on this parameter want to bring the elapsed time down by analyzing the request on elapsed time basis

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase it in simple words:

1. You ran a JMeter test from your location and got results 1
2. You ran a manual test using browser from your location and got results 2
3. You compared results 1 to results 2 and they were similar
4. You ran a JMeter test from location close to the system under test and got results 3
5. Now you're asking why results 3 differ from results 1 and 2. Shouldn't you run your "manual test" from the location close to the system under test?

Also looking into response time only doesn't tell the full story, consider analyzing [Connect Time](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/%7Eagupta/cs340/project2/TCPIP_State_Transition_Diagram.pdf) and [Latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) as well.

In general for finding application defects it doesn't really matter where the load generator is located and how long does it take for the request to reach the server and the response to get back over the wire, this time is more or less the same and you can get it by subtracting Latency from the Elapsed Time.

Server processing time is what you're looking for and after certain threshold it will be increasing as the load increases.

If application owner wants application to react fast in Asia or Australia he should consider deploying instances closer to the end users and route the traffic to this or that instance basing on the user IP address.

More information on metrics, what they mean and how to analyze them:

- [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)
- [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites)

Comment: Hey Dmitri thanks for your response i understand what you are trying to say but i ran the manual run too on the server and noted the performance and the performance of manual run on server was similar to manual local system performance. But the JMeter performance was really faster than the manual run on server

Comment: The Latency on server was zero for most requests but on local machine it was larger also the manual performance time on Server and local system were almost identical but jmeter results on server were way off from manual results on server